# php json_encode() shows null with Arabic characters

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I print array with `json_encode()` it does not show Arabic usernames, what can I do to show these user names properly?

```
$cnx = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "pass", "databasename" );
$data = mysqli_query( $cnx, "SELECT userid,username FROM user" );
$getalluser = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $data ) )
  $getalluser[] = array( $row[ "username" ],
                         "http://localhost/test/image.php?u=" . $row[ "userid" ],
                         $row[ "username" ] );
echo json_encode($getalluser);
```

AND when i used befor query

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

the result shows like this `\u00ca\u00c7\u00e3\u00d1`

I am using PHP 5.2

---

The solution at the moment , use `iconv()`

```
   $users[] = array( iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', ($row[ "username" ])),
                         "http://localhost/386/image.php?u=" . $row[ "userid" ],
                         iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', ($row[ "username" ] );
```

Comment: Using mysqli instead of mysql, you need a line `mysqli_set_charset($cnx, 'utf8');`, not `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`.

Comment: @julp thanks brother i used `iconv()` to convert result to `utf` and it working very good

Comment: Huh, I don't understand: if you ask MySQL to return the result set in utf8 (it's the purpose of mysqli_set_charset), how can you need, behind, to do a conversion in UTF-8 of something that should already be in UTF-8? Your data are "corrupted" into the database in the first place? (ie a SET NAMES is missing at INSERT)

Answer (score 0):

try changing in you database in the console:

```
ALTER TABLE 'user' MODIFY 'username' VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

in the varchar() function sets your custom length of chars.

then in you php at the very beginning of all:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

That should work.

Comment: thanks brother , but i don't want edit or convert any table on my database , i want the solution or edit only in php code

Comment: user table is `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: if you think the problem is JSON, the answer is not. JSON not changes nothing, all depends of file encoding as utf8 etc.

Comment: okay but sure there is ways to `encoding` array to `UTF` with `JSON`, right ?

Comment: The solution is easy just use `iconv('windows-1256', 'utf-8', ($row[ "username" ]`

Comment: Ok this was the only answer for me that worked, but why when changing my char length from 255 to 32 work?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was having a very similar issue and I tried it all setting up my `UTF8` on my page, to my db to my connect and nothing worked.

I finally figured out that I was using `ucfirst` with the string and some characters do not convert and in turn it was breaking my array I was trying to `json_encode`.

Also I was using `substr` and that was breaking it as well trying to shorten the length of the string if it was more than 60 characters.